# Detect if model has table associated

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I have lots of models in my CakePHP 2 project, and I would like know if has certain model has a table associated to it.

For instance, I have models that are pure-logic purpose, that have no tables associated to it, but also, I have models which require tables;

> **EfscModel2.php**

```
class EfscModel2 extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'table_2';
}
```

> **SomeController.php**

```
$tableName = 'get table name from EfscModel2';
```

What is the best approach for this?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you not just check the `$useTable` property to see if it has a value?

Answer (score 0):

As @waterloomatt commented, you can just check the $useTable property of the model.

If you use the EfscModel2  model in the "SomeController", then

`$tableName = $this->EfscModel2->useTable`,

otherwise you need to initialize the model first using the ClassRegistry:

`$efscModel2 = ClassRegistry::init('EfscModel2')
$tableName = efscModel2->useTable`